# Обработка событий по изменению полей в таблице

Tags: sql-server, sql

Стоит задача создания возможности подписки на определенное событие(изменение) в базе данных. Т.е при изменении в определенной таблице(ах) определенного поля(ей), допустим, уведомлять некоторых юзеров письмом. Причем, создание такой рассылки должно выполняться на web-страничке админом, т.е. без внесения изменений в базу руками.

Пока единственное что приходит на ум, это выбор админом на страничке таблицы и поля, и генерация простейшего триггера, который будет добавлять запись в таблицу `Events`, а уже к этой таблице будет обращаться сервис и слать почту. При желании более сложного события, давать админу заполнять тело триггера.

Вопрос:  сколько теоретически можно создавать триггеров на базу\таблицу, как это будет влиять на производительность?
Как поддерживать актуальной схему бд в системе контроля версий?
Может подскажете более удачный способ отслеживания изменений в базе?
sql server 2008r2, в будущем 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сколько у вас разных вопросов :). По порядку:

1) Судя по тому, что уже имеющееся требование — отсылать письма — не укладывается в SQL код, то последующие расширения событий тоже могут не укладываться. Поэтому очевидно, что логика событий должна быть не в сиквеле. Предложенный вами вариант вполне нормальный, особенно если нет жестких требований к времени отклика, чтобы пинговать табличку Event пореже.

Однако можно посмотреть на этот вопрос с другой стороны: КТО и ПОЧЕМУ пишет сразу в базу, раз вы думаете о том, как отслеживать изменения в базе? Если туда пишет ваше приложение, так отслеживайте изменения сразу в нем. Если туда пишет стороннее приложение, пусть оно пишет опять же через ваш АПИ, и вы будете отслеживать изменения. Подумайте на этот счет.

2) По поводу количества триггеров в базе и на таблицу. Их количество ограничено только количеством объектов в БД. Для сиквела 2005 и раньше размер можнопосмотреть здесь: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2005/maximum-capacity-specifications.aspx

На производительность триггеры влияют ровно настолько, сколько у вас там логики напихано. В вашем случае это будет дополнительный insert.

3) По поводу поддержки актуальной схемы БД с системе контроля версий (вопрос, на самом деле заслуживает отдельного обсуждения). Распространенный вариант таков: скриптуете вашу текущую схему, кладете в систему контроля версий. Все последующие изменения схемы оформляете апгрейд скриптами и кладете туда же. Важно:

а) скрипты должны быть rerunable,

б) скрипты должны иметь версию

Например:

Script1.0 -- базовая версия схемы

Script1.1 -- добавили таблицу Event

Script1.2 -- добавили новую колонку в таблицу Event

И так далее. Т.о., прогнав последовательно скрипты с начала и до конкретной версии, вы получаете базу со схемой, соответствующей данной версии. Версии скриптов имеет смысл синхронизировать с версией приложения.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. В базу вносят изменения сразу несколько приложений, доступа к которым нет, поэтому переписать под api не получится. По поводу схемы: нужно как-то знать какие админ добавил триггеры, что бы не искать по всей базе. Допустим, при создании триггера заносить его код в отдельную таблицу?

Comment: Не понял, зачем вам нужно знать про триггеры?